# Want to join two tables with specific condition

Tags: sql

I would like to do a specific join query with two tables
The First one contain many records in dates, the second one just few dates but that means that the records should be continuous starting from that date, that is an example :
TABLE 1

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Date 1 | Cell 1 |
| Date 2 | Cell 2 |
| Date 3 | Cell 3 |
| Date 4 | Cell 4 |

TABLE2

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Date 1 | Cell 1 |
| Date 2 | Cell 2 |

The join I want to get is :
Table2.Date <= Table1.Day
and record=cell
and if there is no records for Table2.Date <= Table1.Day join the min of table 2 to table 1

| Column A | Column B | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Date 1 | Record 1 | Date 1 | Cell 1 |
| Date 2 | Record 2 | Date 1 | Cell 1 |
| Date 3 | Record 3 | Date 1 | Cell 1 |
| Date 4 | Record 4 | Date 2 | Cell 2 |

...

Please HELP

```
this is the query I am trying to type :
SELECT TOP 100 RECORD_DATE,NAME, T2.NAME, T2.DATE_ FROM T1
Join  T2
ON T1.NAME = T2.NAME  
AND 
(   
    SELECT MAX(DATE_) 
    FROM T2
    WHERE NAME=T1.NAME AND DATE_<=T1.RECORD_DATE
    
)<=  T1.RECORD_DATE
ORDER BY RECORD_DATE DESC
```

Comment: Note that the `TOP n` clause doesn't exist in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer partially, but for the first records when if T2.date are bigger than T1.date and we need to join them, I'm still not able to do it :

```
SELECT RECORD_DATE,NAME, T2.NAME, MAX(T2.DATE_) FROM  T1
Join  T2
ON T1.NAME = T2.NAME  
WHERE DATE_<=T1.RECORD_DATE 
GROUP BY RECORD_DATE, NAME, T2.NAME
ORDER BY RECORD_DATE DESC
```